# Spark (Python) Investigate task content

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

If I understand documentation right, the size of task should be kept as small as possible (desirably below 100kB). As I started writing my code I sticked to OOP, which I think now backfires because my tasks are 132kB big.

How can I inspect task contents to identify points of improvement? Is it worth optimizing with 32% over the suggested limit?

EDIT
The problem was that I was using sc.parallelize(). It seems that this method is not intended as a way to import data into Spark framework. I found out it was the reason because the warning showed warning message with task size linearly dependant on data set size I was trying to parallelize.

Comment: Use the Spark history server?  http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html

Comment: @cricket_007 That does not sound like an answer, are you just guessing or your response is based on some knowledge?

I need to know which parts of my code contribute to size of task, I doubt history server will provide detailed info on this.

Comment: It's a comment, not an answer. I know from experience that you can view the logs of the jobs and see the DAG of the execution path. Could you at least try it before calling someone out for lack of knowledge?

Comment: I read about history server earlier and had not spotted anything that I considered useful. I'm sorry if you felt offended, your comment was short and included a question mark at the end. Had you included pieces of information from the second message, I would not have asked that way. SO has many users blindly pasting links to documentation, without having any more background. Sorry again.
I'm running Spark locally in a Docker container. I will attempt to set up a history server and share if successful.

Comment: That's fine. No offense taken. I don't know if this is what you're looking for, but there's a storage tab of the Web UI.  https://www.mapr.com/sites/default/files/blogimages/Spark-RDD-storage.png

Comment: I went through all tabs of history server (easy to setup cause it's active by default when cluster is running). I can only find size of RDD input size to each stage/task, it does not show task size. I wonder if what I want is feasible since code is written in Python and if I get it right it's transpiled into Java.

Comment: Actually Scala, but running in the JVM, so almost Java. I'm not quite sure I understand "task size". Isn't that entirely dependant upon the size of the input data?

Comment: From docs: ```Prior to execution, Spark computes the task’s closure. The closure is those variables and methods which must be visible for the executor to perform its computations on the RDD```. I think that due to OOP code when there is let's say a list of objects in the closure, there is an overhead due to the fact that each of them has it's own methods.

Comment: Sure. To address the question, though, 100kB seems really small considering Spark is used for jobs on petabytes of data